# Boost mutex and class member access

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, private-members

I have hit a problem while trying to use [BOOST threads 1.53.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread.html). Since I am a newbie to BOOST, I have now a problem where a large class from a project needs to have some thread mode processing.

While compiling the code I kept getting the error:

```
error C2248: 'boost::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::mutex'
```

Which are reading through online I figured it out that using Boost's lock_guard, it turned out statements like the one below

```
PointPorcessor processor = PointProcessor(x,y,z);
```

Is creating a instance of the class and and assigning it to `processor` variable. (or am I wrong?). Which basically means boost will now allow mutex to be copied

The class itself

```
PointProcessor
{
boost::mutex mtex; // The one and only mutex
// Other members
};
```

I can use pointers instead like
PointProcessor* processor = new  PointProcessor(x,y,z)
The problem is, this is a large codebase and I don't want to change rest of the implementations to `PointProcessor* processor = new PointProcessor` where as they are just `PointProcessor processor  = PointProcessor(x,y,z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that here:

```
PointPorcessor processor = PointProcessor(x, y, z);
```

You are creating `processor` by *copy-initialization*, where a temporary of type `PointProcessor` is default-constructed first, and then `processor` is copy-constructed or move-constructed from that temporary.

However, `boost::mutex` is non-copyable and non-moveable (provided move semantics is supported at all in the version of Boost you are using), which explains why copy-initialization of `processor` is illegal.

You should rather construct your object through *direct-initialization*, this way:

```
PointProcessor processor(x, y, z);
```

Comment: @Wajih: Sure, take your time and let me know :)

Comment: Dude is the man :) I guess I have to start learning C++ again! Thank you indeed!